# Makefile pass-through in a CMake project

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have a project which uses CMake. Most of the project builds with CMake, but there's one subdirectory with a complicated build procedure that doesn't work with CMake. For this one directory, we have a hand-written Makefile. To build this one special directory, we manually copy it over to the build directory and call make on it after we've called cmake && make to build the rest of the project.

What I want CMake to do is just copy over this one directory to the build directory as is, with its existing Makefile, without trying to generate a Makefile. Then when I call make on the top level build directory, it just invokes the hand-written Makefile for this one directory. Is this possible?

Comment: I think this helps with part of your problem: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH.html

Comment: Check add_custom_target() or add_custom_command() if that helps.

Comment: I'd rethink what you are asking.  If you just wholesale copy the directory over then incremental builds won't be possible.  You really want a Makefile that supports sources in one directory and builds in another.  Also consider `https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/module/ExternalProject.html` which will generate custom targets and commands for you instead of making them yourself.

Comment: I'd certainly like it to do incremental builds of the special directory.

Answer (score -1):

I short: Yes, this is possible.

Steps:

1. Copy the [Directory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy)
2. Add the Makefile as a build step using either [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) or [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) depending on the purpose of the makefile

Comment: This won't work if you make any source code changes; subsequent `make` will not recopy the changed source code files.

Comment: To be fair: the question was not clear whether this was needed.